# Split itext 7 pdf row if there is more data that doesn't fit in one page

Tags: itext7

`cell.setKeepTogether(true)` is working fine but when cell has more data which doesn't fit in one page it is going to endless loop and pdf page is not generating.

In itext 5 we `setSplitlate(true)` which will split to next page if cell data doesn't fit in one page. But how can we achieve this in itext 7. If I don't use `cell.setKeepTogether(true)` it is working fine. But I don't want split to next page if cell data is small. I want to split to next page only if I have more data that doesn't fit in one page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent splitting row over multiple pages in itext 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50750159/how-to-prevent-splitting-row-over-multiple-pages-in-itext-7)

Comment: You say "when cell has more data which doesn't fit in one page it is going to endless loop and pdf page is not generating.". This seems like a bug. Can you prove your words by providing a reproducible sample?